# Python - How to get each item multiplied by the amount the user inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python3 code, it's a simple grocery list and the user can type the items he wants to buy and then the output is the total cost. But instead of repeating each item multiple times, I want the user to input the amount like..."2chicken, 2tomato" instead of "chicken, chicken, tomato, tomato"..how do i do this?

```
items_dict={"chicken": 50, "fish":30, "tomato":12, "chips":5}
print("Our shop has", tuple(items_dict))
prompt=input("What will you buy?\n").split(', ')
total_price=0

for items in prompt:
    try:
        total_price += items_dict[items]
    except:
        total_price="Some items aren't available to buy."
        break
print ("You have to pay", total_price, "EGP")
```

Input: 2chicken, 22tomato, 100chips

Expected Output: You have to pay 864 EGP.

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? For example, if you have the string `2chicken`, *what is the rule that tells you* that `2` is the quantity and `chicken` is the item? Can you write code to implement that rule? Given the quantity as a string, can you determine the corresponding integer? If you have that integer and the name, can you do the rest of the work? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You check each word of the string to see if it starts with a digit.  Handling one digit is easy.

Comment: loop take while char is a number, like `isnum` on string (i think, maybe wrong). gotta check which is the methods on str thogh, I'd suggest it as helpful at the least.

Comment: your code will probably be significantly simpler if you guide the user through each item individually rather than having them type out a long string that you have to split, split and then calculate. not to mention they could forget commas, or use semicolon...it can get messy.

Comment: This is another solution,

`import re

items_dict={"chicken": 50, "fish":30, "tomato":12, "chips":5}
print("Our shop has", tuple(items_dict))

prompt = input("What will you buy?\n");
arr = re.findall(r'\d+', prompt)

result = ''.join([i for i in prompt if not i.isdigit()]).split(', ')

total_price=0
i = 0
for items in result:
    try:
        total_price += items_dict[items] * int(arr[i])
        i += 1
    except:
        total_price="Some items aren't available to buy."
        break
print ("You have to pay", total_price, "EGP")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have approach this using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20match#re.match) in the following way:

```
import re
items_dict={"chicken": 50, "fish":30, "tomato":12, "chips":5}
print("Our shop has", tuple(items_dict))
prompt=input("What will you buy?\n").split(', ')

total_price=0

for items in prompt:
    match = re.match("(\d+)(\w+)", items) # Here group(1) => (\d+) will match the quantity of item and 
                                          # group(2) => (\w+) will match the name of product.
    try:
        total_price += (int(match.group(1))*items_dict[match.group(2)])
    except:
        total_price="Some items aren't available to buy."
        
print ("You have to pay", total_price, "EGP")
```

Output:

```
Our shop has ('chicken', 'fish', 'tomato', 'chips')
What will you buy?
2chicken, 22tomato, 100chips
You have to pay 864 EGP
```

Comment: Just for explanation: Here `int(match.group(1))` refers to the integer value or the quantity of the item. `match.group(2)` refers to the product name